# How to multiply matrices using 2D Array on Fibonacci Sequence?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

The problem I'm having is that I'm unsure how I can multiply matrices together by the same matrices over and over. What I'm trying to achieve is that I want to be able to update the matrices. Here is my code:

```
int fib3(int a, int b, int n) {
int num[2][2] = { {0,1}, {1,1} };
const int num2[2][2] = { {0,1}, {1,1} };
int factArray[2][1] = { {0}, {1} };
if (n == 0) {
    return a;
}
else if (n == 1) {
    return b;
}
else {

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        num[0][0] = ((num2[0][0] * 0) + num2[0][1] * 1);
        num[0][1] = ((num2[0][0] * 1) + num2[0][1] * 1);
        num[1][0] = ((num2[1][0] * 0) + num2[1][1] * 1);
        num[1][1] = ((num2[1][0] * 1) + num2[1][1] * 1);
    }


    factArray[0][0] = ((num[0][0] * factArray[0][0]) + num[0][1] * factArray[1][0]);
    factArray[1][0] = ((num[1][0] * factArray[0][0]) + num[1][1] * factArray[1][0]);

    return factArray[0][0];
}
```

Here I would take the previous matrices and multiply it by a constant matrices, but I am unsure how to update the matrices as I do.

So the matrices is raised to some power.

So for example, I want to find f(5) the 5th Fibonacci sequence , which should be 5, and I am getting 1 as the result in the programming.

Comment: Please remove the link to the image and post the code here.

Comment: Past code here pls !

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: @user4630535818  The issue is that I do not know how I could take a 2x2 matrices and raise it to some power. The problem in the code I do know is that I'm reassigning the value of the 2d array which then is problematic.

Comment: @kingw3 I want it to be faster than a recursive function definition of the Fibonacci Sequence. I want an iterative function implementation with matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula in matrix representation is mainly of interest for theoretical analysis. The trick is that you can have always two elements of the sequence in the vector instead of having to refer to earlier elements of the sequence. However, to implement it I dont see the benefit compared to using the recursive formula. Condsider that

```
 | 1 1 |   | a |    | a+b |
 | 1 0 | * | b | =  | a   |
```

Hence the matrix multiplication effectively does exactly the same: add the last two elements, remeber current one (`a`).

That being said, your code has some problems:

- you pass `a` and `b` but you only ever use them for the first and second element of the sequence. You dont need `a` and `b`. The initial values are already in the starting value of the matrix.
- you have a loop, but in each iteration you calculate the same values and write them into the same array elements.
- I cannot really follow the logic of your code. Why is there another multiplication after the loop? The [matrix formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) says, in a nutshell, "take some starting vector, apply a matrix `n` times, done". To be honest I cannot find that anywhere in your code ;)

If you insist on using matrix multiplications, I would suggest to stay away from c-style arrays. They don't like to be passed around. Use `std::array` instead. I have a slight aversion against nesting, hence I'd suggest to use

```
constexpr size_t N = 2;
using matrix = std::array<int,N*N>;
using vector = std::array<int,N>;
```

`std::array`s can be returned with no pain:

```
vector multiply(const matrix& a,const vector& b) {
    vector result;
    auto ma = [&a](size_t row,size_t col) { return a[row*N+col];};    
    result[0] = ma(0,0)*b[0] + ma(0,1)*b[1];
    result[1] = ma(1,0)*b[0] + ma(1,1)*b[1];
    return result;
}
```

Now it should be straight-forward to implement the fibonacci sequence.

[Spoiler Alert](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VKhEFFjfbZLmthv1)